# Bootstrap5 JavaScript functions are not working in shadow DOM lit element

Tags: bootstrap-5, lit-element, lit

I have implemented web component using LIT Element and integrated bootstrap5 in it.
when I try to call modal/popovers/tooltip etc... it is not working.

```html
render(){
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
```

when I click on button it is not responding.
Can any one help me how to enable the JavaScript functionality in LIT Element.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Could you create a real example with an actual element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in Bootstrap but i think that Bootstrap‘s Javascript is not able to find the elements which are normally found by using data attributes. I would expect that you have to init the plug-ins by calling the bootstrap javascript directly and pass the dom element or not to use shadowRoot inside your components.